# Aggregate class extending base class - Violation of LSP?

Tags: aggregate, liskov-substitution-principle

The [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) (LSP) on Wikipedia

---

Say I have a `Alien` class with an `numFingers` attribute*.  Occasionally, I need to pull the sum of the `numFingers` from the database, grouped by other field values.  In these cases, I have no need to manipulate each record individually, but I do need access to a lot of their functionality -- be able to get attributes, perform some basic logic on them, etc.  This may include data summed from thousands of records, so it makes little sense to instantiate thousands of `Alien` objects when the database query can do the work of summing for me.

I would like to make an extension class called `AlienAggregate`, whose attributes are set from the grouped & summed query.  This class would allow me to call any of `Alien`'s methods.  The *only* difference between functionality of the two classes, is `GetID()`.  The aggregate class has no ID, since its data has been derived from any number of records.  Because of this, calling `GetID()` on `AlienAggregate` throws an exception.

Is this a violation of the Liskov Substitution Principle?  Is there a better way to handle a call to `GetID()`?  Is there a better way to design the relationship between the `Alien` and `AlienAggregate` classes?

<sub>*Actual names may have been changed just because I can.</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you're violating `LSP` since the principle only applies when `Alien` is a subtype of `AlienAggregate` (or the other way around).  There is no `is a` relationship here (more of an aggregation of `Alien`'s as you've appropriately named them).

Instead, it sounds like both `Alien`, and `AlienAggregate` probably implement a `LooksAlien` Interface.  The `Alien` class just has an additional method, GetID().

...just beware of the nefarious `BeginInvasion` method on `AlienAggregate`.

Comment: I want AlienAggregate to extend Alien, because I need the same logic in both classes.

Comment: I'm finding it ironic you're worried about violating LSP, but not worried about making AlienAggregate a subclass of Alien when clearly they don't have an `is a` relationship, but a `has a`.  You need the same logic in both classes...so factor it out into it's own class, and give both classes access to it either via an interface, or with a reference to an instantiated instance of it.

Comment: Well, it's not really a `has a` relationship... because it doesn't "have" any aliens, just an aggregation of some data from aliens.  But I think you're right about moving the logic into a separate class.  Then `Alien` and `AlienAggregate` will just share common attributes.